# OnConnect() Callback is not getting called using mosquitto C

Tags: c++, c, mosquitto

Using mosquitto, I am trying to push data into AWS. mosquitto_connect() function is executing successfully but onConnect() function is not getting called for some unknown reason. onDisconnect() returns an error code 7 which means MOSQ_ERR_CONN_LOST. I am clueless how to deal with this.

Note : Same program used to work previously but now throwing error.

```
static void onDisconnect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, int rc){
  std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" : "<<__LINE__<<" : "<<mosquitto_strerror(rc)<<std::endl;
  cout << "disconnect status..." << rc << endl; 
  // mosquitto_loop_stop(mosq, false);  (void)obj, (void)mosq;
}


static void onConnect(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int result){
 std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" : "<<__LINE__<<" : mosquitto connect callback succeed. \n "<<std::endl;  
} 


static void onCallback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int level, const char *str){
// Pring all log messages regardless of level.       (void)mosq, (void)userdata, (void)level;   std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" : "<<str<<std::endl; 
} 

mosquitto_lib_init();
struct mosquitto * mosq = NULL;
const char *clientId = "ClientId";        
mosq = mosquitto_new(clientId, true, NULL);

if (!mosq) { 
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" : "<<__LINE__<<" mosquitto_new failed. \n "<<std::endl;  
    return;
}else
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<" : "<<__LINE__<<" mosquitto_new succeed. \n "<<std::endl;    

mosquitto_tls_opts_set(mosq, 1, NULL, NULL);       
mosquitto_tls_set(mosq, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", NULL,                            
                        "/opt/usr_data/tests/LoaderPoc/certs/cert.pem",                            
                        "/opt/usr_data/tests/LoaderPoc/certs/privkey.pem", NULL);                                  

mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, onConnect);
mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(mosq, onDisconnect);    
mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosq, onCallback);    
//mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mosq, onPublish);    

const char *host = "a2eg3przjv23yh.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";     
auto ret = mosquitto_connect(mosq, host, 8883, 60);
    cout << "connection status.." << ret <<endl;        

auto loop_ret = mosquitto_loop_start(mosq);
    cout << "Loop status..." << loop_ret << endl;
```

```
Output
MachineAppOnBoardManager::onCallback : Client ClientId sending CONNECT
MachineAppOnBoardManager::onDisconnect : 160 : The connection was lost.
disconnect status...7
```

Comment: could you try to replace `mosquitto_connect` with `mosquitto_connect_async` -- so that the loop is already running when the connect is executed

Comment: I have already done that but  ... no luck ! BTW thanks for response @florgeng

Comment: Without TLS I've done much the same thing as you successfully. Init/New/Authorization/On_connect/On_disconnect/Connect. As soon as I enter the loop I get the connect callback run (not before, which is why I was looking here). If I send a bad username I get an error code on the connect callback and then a disconnect callback.